# How do you create a multi step form in flutterflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need help with creating a multi-step form in flutter flow.

I have searched for material to help but nothing related to flutterflow. I had a glimmer of hope when I chanced on the possibility of adding a [widget](https://pub.dev/packages/cool_stepper) from pub.dev for use in my project. It's a multi-step form widget from https://pub.dev/packages/cool_stepper however when I try to follow the [documentation](https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/custom-widgets#1.-choosing-a-package) from flutterflow about how to add a widget, I don't know what parameters to add to get it to work and how to utilize the widget in my project.

I will be grateful for some help and direction or better still a more feasible way of achieving this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [PageView](https://docs.flutterflow.io/widgets-and-components/widgets-ui-elements/layout-elements/pageview) to divide your form into pages and [Form](https://docs.flutterflow.io/widgets-and-components/widgets-ui-elements/form-elements-1/form) to validate your fields.

You can use as reference [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMpzgVBAg88), that creates an onboarding page using PageView.